# Forward a host's network traffic to another host with the exception of SSH traffic

Tags: networking, iptables

I am trying to redirect all the network traffic received in a old host to a different host. For that I created two new rules with `iptables` on the old host:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d old_machine_ip -j DNAT --to-destination new_machine_IP
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s new_machine_ip -j SNAT --to-source old_machine_ip
/etc/init.d/iptables save
/etc/init.d/iptables restart
```

Everything worked perfectly however I cannot access the old host with `ssh` any more since it redirects it to the new host. I would like to know if it is possible to create a single rule that ignores the prerouting for the ssh service.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d old_machine_ip \
  -j DNAT --to-destination new_machine_IP
```

to

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d old_machine_ip -p tcp \! --dport 22 \
  -j DNAT --to-destination new_machine_IP
```

Comment: Sorry but this command is not work. Even if i define the -p tcp for port 22 :S

Comment: "Doesn't work" meaning what? An error message or that you still cannot use SSH?

Comment: An error message. i think dport cannot be used without specifying the protocol. e.g -p tcp and the dport 22.

Comment: @Winter But in your earlier comment you wrote "Even if i define the -p tcp for port 22"... You should not accept an answer until it works.